# how to update int in firestore array from app?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update the likes on a post from the app when a button is pressed. The posts are located in an array and I'm trying to update the int of the likes of the post.

Below is the firestore
[image]

This is the button code. It isn't working.
[image]

Comment: There is no way to update an item in an array by an index. You'll have to read the document, get the current value for the `posts` array, update that, and write the entire (updated) array back to the database.

Comment: so how do i read the likes number and update it?

Comment: Exactly as I said: read the document, get the array from it, update the value, and write the entire array back to the document.